# How to fetch polymorphic relation matching data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, polymorphism

I have three tables Jobseekers, Preferences and Industries. Preferences table is foreign table of Jobseeker and Preferences is connected with Industries table with polymorphic relation.
Table structure as below:

**jobseekers**
id:
name:
email:
Phone:

**preference**
id: 
job_title: 
Location: 
Salary:
jobseeker_id:

**industryables**
industry_id: 2
industryable_id: 1
industryable_type: App\Models\Preference

I am now able to store and fetch all data using this technique, but how can I fetch specific data based on industry. For example, if I want to fetch those jobseekers only who match certain Industry id, or I want to pass industry id on query and fetch matching jobseekers and show their profiles only. Is it possible or not, please somebody help me.

```
$jobseekers = Jobseeker::with(['preference.industries' => function($query) {
        $query->where('industry_id', '=', 7);
    }])->get();
```

Above code fetching all jobseekers with empty industries array and jobseekers with industry id 7 have industries values. My goal is to fetch only those jobseekers who have industry id 7 or something like that.

Comment: Please post your code so far

Comment: Please check i have updated my post with code.

Answer (score 0):

Its a total guess, because

1. You haven't shared the schema of the table so I am guessing how they are linked.
2. You haven't put them in a codepen, so I can't test the query
3. I am unfamiliar with laravel so I can only give you the mysql query.

```sql
select j.*, p.*, i.*  // select the fields you actually want
from jobseekers j
inner join industryables i on i.industryable_id = j.id
left outer join preference p on p.jobseeker_id = j.id
where i.industry_id = 7
```

The **inner join** ensures that you only get the records that exist on both tables (jobseekers and industryables)

Comment: Did it work?  If it did, please tick the answer